# how to internationalize a not-found.tsx page in next with app dir?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm creating a portfolio for my friend, and he wants to have two languages in his whole portfolio, I've already created the pages in english, and I followed the example of i18n that is in the official documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization), it was everything ok, but when i finished it all, and I got to make the not-found.tsx page, I ran into a problem, the root layout it was inside of my dinamic lang page, and the not-found.tsx needs to be in the root of the app dir, but I need to keep the root layout inside the [lang] dir. What can I do to deal with this? It's okay if only the not-found.tsx page is in English

I tried to put the not-found.tsx page inside the [lang] dir, but needs to be in the root of app dir.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.